# How to move TextField's labelText and icon to the right side

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to move the icon and the label text to the right side of the Text Field. I tried `textAlign: TextAlign.right` but it's only for input text.

[image]

```
    TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: 2,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(Icons.description),  
        labelText: 'details',
      ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just found [Directionality](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html) widget and it changes the direction for everything include label and icon

```
Directionality(
 textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
 child: TextFormField(
 textAlign: TextAlign.right,
 textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
 keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
 maxLines: 2,
 decoration: const InputDecoration(
 icon: Icon(Icons.description),  
 labelText: 'details',),   
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use suffixIcon, An icon that appears after the editable part of the text field and after the suffix or suffixText, within the decoration's container.[Official API Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/suffixIcon.html)

```
TextFormField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
       hintText: "Enter a message",
       suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.description),
    ),
),
```

This exactly what you need, you need to customize some style

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 200,
              child: TextFormField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter a message",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.description),
            ),
          ],
    );
  }
```

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable

```
var _controller = TextEditingController();
```

And your `TextField`:

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Enter a message",
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      onPressed: (){},
      icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: what about `labelText`

Answer (score 0):

Try "suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone)"
It will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use of suffixIcon
suffixIcon: Icon(
                      Ionicons.ios_search,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),